# Copy of a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem. I need the old value of a variable. But when I set a new date for this variable then my string value contains the new value too.

How can I solve this in VBA with excel? I know there is the possibility with `byRef` or `byVal`. How can I combine this in my example?

Here the code:

```
Dim ExTagBeschTagString$

ExTagBeschTagString = "First Day: " & .DTPickerFirstDay & vbCrLf & "Second Day: " & .DTPickerSecondDay

If InStr(.TextField.Value, ExTagBeschTagString) Then
  .Anmerkung.Value = Replace(.Anmerkung.Value, ExTagBeschTagString, "")
Else
  .Anmerkung.Value = .Anmerkung
End If
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You'll need to post more code or explain your form more fully.

Comment: @neuralgroove I need the reference value not the upgraded value. Fore example I choose a date for DTPickerFirstDay and a date for DTPickerSecondDay. This values I need to copy in a separate variable. Well, when I take an upgrade and change the values the separate variable has to contains the first chosen values

Comment: I don't think I get it..why not create a second variable and dump the contents of the first variable into that before you change the first variable?

Comment: @neuralgroove Could you do an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
Dim Var1 as integer
Dim Var2 as integer

Var1 = 1
Var2 = Var1
Var1 = 2
```

Then output would be

```
Var1 = 2
Var2 = 1
```

Your question seems to say it's not....